# Is there any way to Hibernate a computer into mechanical off (G3)?

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I hibernate my Windows computer every time I leave it, because I see no reason to keep it running all the time, however I do want to maintain my previous running state when I resume the system.

I've noticed that there are times (and I cannot pinpoint why) my system immediately turns back on after I hibernate it. I'm aware that Hibernation is technically not "off", since things such as WoL and USB can wake the device. What I'm interested in, however, is to completely shut off the power to the system after the hibernation file is saved to disk such that the machine cannot be turned back on in any way other than the mechanical switch on the case.

Given that I'm using Windows 8.1, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your system might be entering hybrid sleep instead of true hibernation. [Microsoft says](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions):

> Hybrid sleep is designed primarily for desktop computers. Hybrid sleep is a combination of sleep and hibernate—it puts any open documents and programs in memory and on your hard disk, and then puts your computer into a low-power state so that you can quickly resume your work. That way, if a power failure occurs, Windows can restore your work from your hard disk. When hybrid sleep is turned on, putting your computer into sleep automatically puts your computer into hybrid sleep. Hybrid sleep is typically turned on by default on desktop computers.

Turn off hybrid sleep by running this command in a Command Prompt window:

```
powercfg /setacvalueindex 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e 0
```

Turn hybrid sleep back on by changing the `0` at the end to a `1` and running it again.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you come out of hybrid sleep? When I hibernate, I turn on the computer and it goes through the full boot process.

Comment: @agent154 The machine should resume almost immediately from hybrid sleep because it's in a low-power state and data in memory is preserved. Resuming from hibernation takes longer because the system is actually off and data that was in memory before hibernation must be loaded from the hard drive.

Comment: Well, in this case it seems that I'm not using Hybrid Sleep. The feature was turned on, but it is only triggered when I go to sleep, not hibernate. My computer actually does turn off (sort of) and when I tap the keyboard, it comes back to life but goes through the full boot process. It's as if it's hibernating, but not cutting full power to the PC, which will then sometimes allow it to randomly wake up on its own.

Comment: That could be it. This [guide to diagnosing automatic wakeups](http://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/) might help.